# How can i set object type to out in oracle stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm beginner in oracle, I've written this oracle object type:

```
create or replace 
TYPE behzadtype AS OBJECT 
( /* TODO enter attribute and method declarations here */ 
  SESSIONID Number,
  myID Number

)
```

and this stored procedure:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1(IDD IN Number) AS 

  t1 behzadtype;
BEGIN
  t1:=behzadtype(12,13);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE VALUES OF SESSION ID ARE: ' || t1.SESSIONID || ' AND OTHE IS:' || t1.myID);

END PROCEDURE1;
```

Up procedure define `IDD IN Number` for input parameter, and I want `t1 behzadtype;` to out parameter, how can I declare it? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204499/how-can-i-use-oracle-object-type-in-store-procedure

Comment: @davegreen100 thanks my friend,but i want define that object to out parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a parameter of the specified type and declare is as an out parameter.

```
create or replace procedure procedure1(IDD IN number, p_out out behzadtype);
```

http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-passing-parameters-procedure-function.htm